# How can I change the coordinate system of gpx-points?

Tags: qgis, gps

I'm working with qgis, v. 2.0.1. I have some points from a gps device (Garmin) and they already are in the .gpx format. Now I have two problems: First, I can't open the gps-Points with the "gpx-tools" plugin by simply choosing "load gpx file". I always have to use the gpx-converter, otherwise the points don't appear in the map window. But actually it should work with "load gpx file", shouldn't it?
The second problem is that I want to change the coordinate reference system of the points from WGS84-EPSG:4326 to CH1903/LV03-EPSG:21781. But as soon as I do this, the points disappear...What can I do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For your first problem, make sure the point layer is loaded in WGS84. You can also use `Add vector layer` to load GPX files.

If you want the points in another CRS, **don't** use `SET CRS for layer`. The right way is to save the data with `Rightclick -> Save As ...` and choose the wanted CRS and another file format like shapefile.

GPX is always treated as WGS84.